# How to account for two time variables in GAMM?

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm trying to fit a Generalized Additive Mixed Model to my data, but I have a hard time conceptualizing how to deal with the following (it's a fictional example, but conceptually similar to the data I'm dealing with):

The dataset is about the effect of 4 different treatments (i.e. 4 groups of animals) on response X (let's say weight) in pregnant animals. The treatment was started on a specific date (same for all animals), but at that time the animals were at a different week into their pregnancy. Obviously, weight increases during pregnancy, so in the GAMM I have to account for the number of weeks into pregnancy as well as weeks into experiment.

This shows the data structure (numbers are fictional; I didn't add any values for the response variable "weight" because I'm not sure how to simulate them):

```
df <- data.frame(animal = rep(paste0("A", 1:40), each=10),
                 group = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=100),
                 exp_wk = 0:9) %>% 
  mutate(preg_wk = rep(sample(10:40, size=40, replace=T), each=10) + exp_wk ,
         weight= NA)
```

I find it difficult to establish what model to start with, especially because of the obvious relationship between preg_wk and exp_wk (if one goes up by 1, the other does to). The hypotheses I would like to test:

- There is a non-linear relationship between the response variable (weight) and the week into the experiment that depends on the intervention group
- There is a non-linear relationship between the response variable (weight) and the week into pregnancy that depends on the intervention group

E.g.

```
m1 <- bam(weight ~ s(exp_wk, by=group) +
            s(preg_wk, by=group) +
            s(animal, bs="re") +
            s(exp_wk , animal, bs="fs", m=1) +
            s(preg_wk, animal, bs="fs", m=1) +
            ti(exp_wk , preg_wk, by=group, d=2), 
          data = df)
```

My rationale:

- `s(exp_wk, by=group)` reflects the non-linear relationship between the response variable and the week into the experiment for each of the 4 groups.
- `s(preg_wk, by=group)` accounts for the change in weight depending on the week into pregnancy, which may depend on group.
- `s(animal, bs="re")` adds a random effect for each animal (different intercepts) and `s(exp_wk, animal, bs="fs", m=1)` and `s(preg_wk, animal, bs="fs", m=1)` adds non-linear random effects for each animal depending on the week into the experiment/pregnancy.
- I was thinking of including `ti(exp_wk, preg_wk, by=group, d=c(2))` to account for the interaction between week into experiment and week into pregnancy by group. I included `d=2` to specify that these two variables are in the same dimension (i.e. time).
- I was also planning to include rho & AR.start to account for temporal autocorrelation

I would appreciate it if someone could let me know if this is a sensible way to go or how I should modify my approach.